# Click event does not send value of parameter

Tags: angular

I try to send some values in onclick event of some links. Onclick event fires but it doesn't send any parameter.

```
<a *ngFor="let item of langs" href="javascript:;" (onclick)="onClick(item.Lang)">{{item.Name}}</a>

@HostListener("click")
onClick(lang: string) {
this._eService.chanegeLang(lang)
.subscribe(resData => this.DoIt(), 
resError => this.errorMsg = resError); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually working based on the [Decorator(@HostListener)](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) in your case, where the first argument would be [`eventName`](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener#eventName) as per documentation.

To make it work use [`click` event in the template](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding), there is no need for `on` prefix.

***Template :***

```
<a *ngFor="let item of langs" href="javascript:;" (click)="onClick(item.Lang)">{{item.Name}}</a>
```

***TS :***

```
onClick(lang: string) {
  this._eService.chanegeLang(lang)
   .subscribe(
     resData => this.DoIt(), 
     resError => this.errorMsg = resError
   ); 
}
```

As per [angular docs :](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding)

> Angular event binding syntax consists of a target event name within parentheses on the left of an equal sign, and a quoted template statement on the right. The following event binding listens for the button's click events, calling the component's onSave() method whenever a click occurs:
>   [image]